# Eclipse IDE is not working

Tags: android

Showing Failed to load the JNI shared library "c:\program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.6.0\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".

Please let me know what the problem is thanks in advance.

Comment: high time for android studio?

Answer (score 2):

It may be difficult to get some help with Eclipse IDE for android nowadays.

I suggest you migrate your project to Android Studio which is the official IDE for android development.

Android Studio has a nice migration tool for Eclipse projects.